# How to recover a bot made with Azure Bot Service (Botframework)?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

While working on my bot through Microsoft Azure's "Bot Sevice" template, I clicked "save" on a change to index.js, and received an error "Unable to save," but then the entire file went blank, and I lost all the code for my bot - which was already live! It is deployed through Bot Framework to places like Slack, Kik, Facebook and others...

Is there a way to recover this file? The only version I have backed up locally is too old to be much use.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to press `Ctrl + z` to undo your changes?

Comment: I didn't make the changes so I can't CTRL Z. Azure corrupted the file. 

And it's configured exactly the way it came from the Azure template.

Comment: Can you share the name of your bot?

Comment: @Lars AutoCompete / AutoCompeteBot

Comment: @Justin - the Azure folks have been working on this.  My understanding is that your code has been restored?   Is that correct?

Comment: @Lars That's true! The Twitter support team was able to provide me a one-time use support ticket, and they were able to restore an earlier version of my code.

Comment: Great!  Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: @Lars All's well that ends well. Really loving the Azure / BotFramework platform. After a lot of headaches trying other methods, this has been a breeze.

Comment: @Justin - glad to hear.  Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for helping us identify a bug!