# Azure Bot code seems to be erased

Tags: azure, bots, botframework

I'm working on a bot (in testing) using the Azure Bot framework and the chat embed code. I had started from the LUIS framework template and embedded it into a section of my website several days ago. It was working as expected, but now all of the files/code for it (using the Azure editor) seem to be erased and the chat embed throws a 502.

This looks like it may be similar to this: [How to recover a bot made with Azure Bot Service (Botframework)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41560036/how-to-recover-a-bot-made-with-azure-bot-service-botframework)

But that did not have an answer that I could work on for my end.

This is just a test bot (so I didn't use the continuous integration/source control anyhow), and mostly for learning at this point, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What time did you first notice this?  Have you tried signing out and signing back in? Does your bot still show up in the dev portal dev.botframework.com ?

Comment: I noticed it this evening. I've tried signing out and back in again. And it shows up in dev.botframework.com but it does not work, and throws an internal server error when I test it.

Comment: https://[YourBotId].scm.azurewebsites.net  <-- does the Kudo Console still work?

Comment: I've been told: "the 502 from Web Chat means the bot is throwing an error."  But, that shouldn't bring down Azure's interface.

Comment: The scm.azurewebsites.net link does not seem to work. 

And the dev.botframework.com link to the bot now throws an exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Whenever I've seen "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on the dev portal, signing out, closing all browser tabs, and signing back in has remedied it.  However, scm.azurewebsites.net not working sounds like something else entirely.  What is your BotId?

Comment: https://lawliobot.scm.azurewebsites.net/

I am not getting "The user name or password is incorrect."

Comment: I apologize for not responding sooner.  The developers believe its a bug on our side, and are certain your bot is not lost.  They are actively investigating and intend on releasing a fix as soon as possible.

Comment: The issue is currently being addressed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick followup!

Comment: Hello, I wanted to follow up on this. The bot code is still missing. Have you had a chance to see if that bug was the root? And is there any way to recover the lost source code? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry it has been a few days without an update.  The bot code is definitely not lost.  We apologize for the inconvenience and frustration.  I'll post an answer in a few minutes detailing how it can be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the Azure Storage Explorer from here: http://storageexplorer.com/

Login, and navigate to your resource group's Storage Account.  When you open it, you'll see File Shares.  There you'll find the source for your bot.

[image: Azure Storage Explorer]

The Bot Service and Bot Framework are currently in preview and being improved upon daily.  We apologize for this inconvenience, and hope your future experiences with the Bot Framework are productive and enjoyable.