# Azure Bot Service - "An internal Error occured at the server"

Tags: botframework

I have created a bot service app in Azure that works fine when I create it. I go through the Microsoft App ID, password screen and it loads the chat emulator and code in browser (using the LUIS template and node.js language). After sometime, if I go back to load that app service from Azure dashboard, it keeps giving me "An Internal error occurred at the server" error message. I am not sure if I shouldn't be going to the newly created Bot Service from dashboard? I did this 3-4 times already, with new names, new RG etc., it's the same issue every time.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what I am doing incorrect to deserve a negative vote. I did see few articles that reported internal server error. However, they were all during creation of the bot steps (explained in https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/52f62e38-bbfb-4b60-939b-f6e9e0fd01a0/unable-to-create-a-bot-service-in-azure?forum=windowsazuremanagement). However, my issue isn't there. It's when I go back to open that app to load the code and emulator in browser, I get that message. I've tried multiple OSs, browsers and also created the entire bot app from scratch 4 times already. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's an issue inside the Bot Service that is currently being addressed.

Comment: Having this issue as well.

Comment: This issue has been fixed.  Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268966/azure-bot-code-seems-to-be-erased  for how to access the code for bots that had this problem.  Newly created bots using the Azure Bot Service will not experience this anymore.  We apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this looks like a bug, there are are two open issues right now on the SDK's repo that look very similar to yours. Here is one of them; ['InternalServerError - Bot & QnA Maker'](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder/issues/2572).

Regarding the downvote, it might be because there isn't a screenshot of the issue which usually helps in answering questions. Also, explaining the steps you undertook or compared against would have helped give a clearer picture for the community to answer.